# native notification android code in cordova plugin java class

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, android-notifications, cordova-plugins

I'm some what aware of cordova and now I'm implementing a notification in my plugin class.

I have used the below android code to create the notification in my java class.
I have imported all the packages related to notification.
But i'm getting the notification exception and unable to get the notification

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentTitle("Welcome")
    .setTicker("Click here to see the offers...")
    .setContentText("Click here to see the offers...")
    //.setSmallIcon(1)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(info, notification);
```

And the exception I'm getting is

```
NotificationService(802): Not posting notification with icon==0:     Notification(pri=0 icon=0 contentView=com.ionicframework.dummy292686/0x1090085 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 when=1439564895752 ledARGB=0x0 contentIntent=N deleteIntent=N contentTitle=7 contentText=31 originalPackageName=N originalUserId=0 tickerText=31 kind=[null])
```

Can some body give suggestions to write the notification logic in a cordova plugin java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done some changes in building the notification object and it worked for me.

```
try{
        Log.i(TAG, "In try block of notification");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("My Company")
        .setContentTitle("Welcome")
        .setContentText("Click here to see offers...")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
        notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "In catch block of notification:"+e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide at least a small icon.

Uncomment `.setSmallIcon(1)` and replace the `1` with resource ID for a drawable to be used as the icon in the notification.

Comment: But it is java class and it is saying "cannot find symbol R in   R.drawable.notification_icon.
I dont have any resource class to import in my hybrid application.
@Jim Rhodes